# How to setup a Adonis js app in CyberPanel

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, cyber-panel

I’m having trouble loading the application. When accessing the subdomain an infinite load is shown and nothing happens.

I tried to use several available tutorials and still without success

SSL work
Migration Work

See below

I’m use AdonisJs

> context / {
>
> type appserver
>
> location /home/dominio.com/aplicativo
>
> binPath /usr/bin/node
>
> appType node
>
> startupFile server.js
>
> maxConns 100
>
> rewrite {
>
> }
>
> addDefaultCharset off
>
> }

ThankYou

Comment: Check your Node "binPath" by typing "which node" in console. It may different than default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with using PM2 to run the app and I made a proxy to forward the port.